# 'Must Declare the Scalar Variable' Error When Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Parameterized SQL Statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand, sqlexception, table-valued-parameters

In C# I'm trying to pass a DataTable as a parameter to an SQL statement. The code I have is below:

```
protected virtual void DoDeleteRecords(List<Guid> ids)
{   
    if (ids.Count > 0)
    { 
        DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
        tvp.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Guid));

        foreach (Guid id in ids)
        {
            DataRow row = tvp.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = id;

            tvp.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN ({0})", "@IDTable");

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CoreSettings.ConnectionString);

        using (connection)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlParameter tvpParam = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTable", tvp);
            tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.IDList";

            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when command.ExecuteNonQuery is called, I get the following SqlException error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@IDTable"

I understand that this error is normally associated with missing out the parameter value, but as far as I can tell, I have that.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE** I have modified the question to remove crappy SQL injection-rich code from my example.

Comment: You cannot pass TVPs in ad-hoc statements. Only stored procedure parameters are supported that way. Consider using Dapper; this is uninteresting boilerplate and Dapper does support constructing lists.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Well that would explain it then! Thanks @JeroenMostert

Comment: What is `"DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE...`" trying to achieve as well when `tableName` is a TVP? That would inject a scalar value into the clause. *Also, that type of syntax is a horrific security vulnerability. It's  2021, SQL injection should have been dead years ago.*

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's garbage, of course you can. But the TVP is not being used, OP is just concating a list straight into the query. The correct code is `"DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + idColumnName + " IN (SELECT * FROM @IDTable)"` no `string.Format` necessary. This code looks pretty dangerous anyway, completely open to SQL injection

Comment: @Charlieface you are absolutely correct. I missed the SELECT from the IN. Dang it! Thanks for spotting that. And just for clarity, this is not production code - just something I'm using to test some ideas. And no, one of those ideas is not "how can get my SQL injected to the max"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: I have no idea where you are getting the `tableName` and `columnName`, but if they are user-supplied, then this is open to SQL injection. At the very least, use `QUOTENAME()` to ensure no actual code is injected.

Secondly, you are not actually using the TVP. The code you have is just saying  `IN (@IDTable)` which is not how you use a TVP.

A TVP is just a table variable, and should be used like any other table:

```sql
protected virtual void DoDeleteRecords(List<Guid> ids)
{   
    if (ids.Count == 0)
        return;
    DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
    tvp.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Guid));

    foreach (Guid id in ids)
        tvp.Rows.Add(id);

    const string sql = @"
DELETE FROM table
WHERE idColumnName IN (SELECT * FROM @IDTable);
";

    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CoreSettings.ConnectionString))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@IDTable", SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            Value = tvp,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
            TypeName = "dbo.IDList"
        });

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're quite right, the original code I posted was crap, and I have now amended my question to hard code the table/column names into the SQL statement. There was no real reason for having them as variables concated in. Also, thanks for spotting my mistake with the TVP table. A true face-palm moment!

Comment: I believe you also need `ParameterDirection.Input` (the equivalent of `READONLY` in SQL), have added