# Why doesn't sql query return result when i pass a string to it in where clause?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP-Search-DocumentNumber]  
    @DocumentNumber varchar(100) = NULL,
    @Company_ID varchar(10) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Company_ID= (REPLACE (@Company_ID, '''', ''))
    
    SELECT SalesID, DocumentNumber AS 'DocumentNumber', CompanyID
    FROM Sales
    WHERE (DocumentNumber LIKE '%' + @DocumentNumber+ '%' 
           OR @DocumentNumber IS NULL) 
      AND DocumentNumber IS NOT NULL
      AND ISNULL(Active, 0) = 1 
      AND ISNULL(IsCommited, 0) = 0 
      AND ISNULL(IsCancelled, 0) = 0
      AND CAST(CompanyID AS varchar(10)) IN (@Company_ID)
END
```

From the VB.NET code, I am passing

```
l_objcmd.CommandText = "USP-Search-DocumentNumber"
l_objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

'l_objParam = l_objcmd.Parameters.Add("@SalesID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
'l_objParam.Value = IIf(ViewState("SalesID") = "", Nothing, ViewState("SalesID"))
'l_objParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

l_objParam = l_objcmd.Parameters.Add("@DocumentNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar)
l_objParam.Value = IIf(ViewState("DocumentNumber") = "", Nothing, ViewState("DocumentNumber"))
l_objParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

l_objParam = l_objcmd.Parameters.Add("@Company_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
l_objParam.Value = IIf(Session("DocumentNumberForm_CompanyID") = "", Nothing, Session("DocumentNumberForm_CompanyID"))
l_objParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

l_ObjDs = v_ObjBREngine.ExecuteProcedure(l_objcmd)

If Not IsNothing(l_ObjDs) And l_ObjDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    gvFilterData.DataSource = l_ObjDs.Tables(0).DefaultView
    gvFilterData.DataBind()

    gvFilterData.Columns(0).Visible = True
Else
    l_ObjDs.Tables(0).Rows.Add(l_ObjDs.Tables(0).NewRow())

    gvFilterData.DataSource = l_ObjDs
    gvFilterData.DataBind()

    gvFilterData.Columns(0).Visible = False
End If
```

The `@Company_ID` is passing as "1,2,3" but doesn't return result but when I put directly this in where it works.

I have tried multiple things with it but doesn't work. Why ? I have even used the IN operator but still issue.

Comment: you'll need to share some sample data. Your use of `in` is not correct.

Comment: Are you aware of *any* language that, if you pass a single parameter that is a string and happens to contain commas will instead interpret that as multiple separate parameters? I'm not, and, in common with VB, SQL doesn't either. There are types *designed* for working with multiple values in SQL, such as table-valued parameters. Taking multiple values and turning them into a string in the first place is just creating more problems.

Comment: Your query is looking for a single company whose ID is the string `1,2,3`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh ok, so how do I tackle this?

Comment: The stored procedure has multiple problems - the catch-all parameters, applying `ISNULL` on the fields, guarantees bad performance because any indexes over the fields won't be used. It would be easier to use an ORM like EF Corer and construct the query dynamically, omitting parameters that aren't needed. Eg `if(docNumber!=null) { query=query.Where(sale=>sale.DocumentNumber=docNumber);` effectively adds an `AND` only if `docNumber` has a value. `.Where(sale=>companyIDs.Contains(sale.CompanyId))` creates an `IN (1,2,3)` clause

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Must Declare the Scalar Variable' Error When Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Parameterized SQL Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065761/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-error-when-passing-a-table-valued-parameter-t) Use a TVP to pass in multiple values

Answer (score 0):

This code most likely does not do what you want:

```
CAST(CompanyID AS varchar(10)) IN (@Company_ID)
```

It is exactly equivalent to:

```
CAST(CompanyID AS varchar(10)) = @Company_ID
```

So if `@Comapny_ID` contains `'1,2,3'`, then it only matches another string this exactly the same.

I get the idea that `Company_Id` contains a list of ids that are presumably comma separated values.  If so, you need to do the comparison in some other way.  A common method would be:

```
CAST(CompanyID AS varchar(10)) IN (SELECT s.value FROM string_split(@Company_Id, ',') s)
```

In older versions, one method is:

```
CONCAT(',', CompanyID, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', @Company_Id, ',%')
```

There may be other ways to pass a list in as well.  This is intended to address what I think the issue is in your code.

Comment: thanks a lot but i am using sql 2k12 so String_Split doesn't work