# Variable number of inserts into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm sending a table (`GridViewRowCollection`) to a method that is responsible for inserting the data into the database. Each row is going to become a row in the database table, it's also user written, so it can be 1 row or 100 rows.

I know how to do it through concatenation, but being user input I need to parametrize it, and doing something dynamic with parametrization I have no idea how to or where to begin.

Can anyone shine some light on this matter?

Comment: Either iterate through the row set, inserting 1 row at a time (which'll be slow) or use a table type parameter.

Comment: Another approach is to pass a JSON string parameter and use `INSERT...SELECT...FROM OPENJSON...`

Comment: It's pretty much the same as with a single insert, but with a variable number of parameters. I would just put an increasing number into the parameter name to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Must Declare the Scalar Variable' Error When Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Parameterized SQL Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065761/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-error-when-passing-a-table-valued-parameter-t)

Comment: That one, left me sorta confused, if I spent some time reading careful it might be a solution, but the solution Crowcoder gave works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do it one-by-one, this would be the pattern. Not shown is robust data validation or exception handling. You **must also change the parameters to meet your needs**, they obviously won't (all) be varchar of length 10. This is partly psuedo code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("the connection string"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // assuming not a stored procedure
    
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Your_Table_Name] (val1, val2, etc.) VALUES (@param1, @param2, etc.);"
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10));
    //etc.
    
    con.Open();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row count; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["param 1"].Value = //whatever value from row
        cmd.Parameters["param 2"].Value = //whatever other value from row
        //etc
        
        int numberOfRowsAffected =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want one of the parameters to stay constant I just need to `AddWithValue` outside of the `for loop` and all the inserts will use that constant parameter, right?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but `AddWithValue` is discouraged since it can lead to inefficiencies or precision loss depending on the data type of the column. Just set the value through the `Value` property and make sure the parameter sqldbtype matches the database..

Answer (score 0):

You could look at SqlBulkCopy

https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-use-sqlbulkcopy-to-do-a-bulk-insert/