# User Defined Table Type Datetime conversion error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tried finding a question on this so far but no luck so thought I'd ask for once!

I've got an app passing a user defined table type back to SQL to use in a stored proc (by converting a class to a table).
Date is '13/04/2021 00:00:00', passing it into a standard datetime column on the user defined table in SQL.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[KeyData] AS TABLE(
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [UnknownDate] [bit] NULL,
    [DateReported] [datetime]  NULL 
)
```

Getting the error of ''Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
The data for table-valued parameter "@KeyData" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.'
I know if I were only passing the parameter I could convert it on the stored proc to type 103 (as im in the UK), but it seems to be erroring when passing the data into the defined table type.

Any ideas?

Edit: Both fields that im passing are nullable datetimes on the C# side as they may not always be required. When they are null and when the date of these is 12/04/2021 it works without any problems.

C# Class:

```
   public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
        public Boolean UnknownDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }
```

C# Code:

```
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyProc", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter test = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KeyData", 
 K.ToTable());
                    test.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                    test.TypeName = "KeyData";

                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    conn.Close();
                }
```

Edit 2: Turned the time into a timespan, still getting the Error. I believe its around the DateReported being '13/04/2021', 12/04/21 works fine. Looks like its trying to pass it in as mm/dd/yyyy. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, why do you have a column called `date`, and a column called `time`, but they are both a `datetime`? Wouldn't the `date` and `time` data type be more appropriate respectively?

Comment: It sounds like you are passing a string parameter that contains your datetime and hoping that converts into the sql datatime column. Instead make your parameter in your stored procedure a datetime and in your app convert your string into a DateTime and then pass that into sql.

Comment: Primary reason for posting this in Webforms and C# is because it may be that people with more C# knowledge recommend adjusting the date format on the webform instead of the SQL side. Edit: Both are Nullable datettimes in the class that im passing. Ill include that info on the post

Comment: @Lambey, I suspect your C# query isn't parameterized.  [Use parameters](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/), with matching data types,  and I bet the problem will be resolved.

Comment: @DanGuzman edited to show my code

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Must Declare the Scalar Variable' Error When Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Parameterized SQL Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065761/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-error-when-passing-a-table-valued-parameter-t) You should just create a new `SqlParameter` with `{SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, TypeName = "KeyData", Value = K.ToTable() }` Then add that with `cmd.Parameters.Add(`

Comment: By the way, I suspect you are not disposing your `conn` connection correctly. It should be in a `using` block

Comment: @Lambey, a SQL Server `time` data type maps to a .NET `TimeSpan` struct so I think you need `public TimeSpan? Time { get; set; }`.

Comment: Thanks all, converted it to a timespan but still getting the error. I believe its around the DateTime of 'DateReported' format. When I pass the date of '12/04/2021' its fine, but the '13/04/21' seems to be causing the error. I think its trying to read it as a mm/dd/yyyy?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue, when converting the class to a datatable, there was no DataType declared on the datetimes. By declaring these as datetimes, it converted sucessfully.

For columns where adding a datetime to a datatable to pass, make sure to use the below on the column.

```
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
```