# Inserting into two tables C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert

I am trying to develop a small POS application, and I need to do some data insertion into database, but I am having troubles inserting into two tables at once.

I am using this stored procedure:

```
// insertpurchase stored procedure

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @id int;

    INSERT INTO tblsuppling_general (Supplier, Bill_nr, Date, Total, Note)
    VALUES (@supplier, @billnr, @date, @total, @note)

    SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();   // here I want to get ID of the insert of the supply and use on every row in second table

    INSERT INTO tblpurchase_details (ID_of_supplying, Barcode, Name, Category, Stock, VAT, QTY, Unit, Supplying_price, Price, Earn_pcs, Bill_nr)
    VALUES (@id, @barcode, @name, @category, @stock, @vat, 1, @unit, @sup_price, @price, @earn, @billnr)

    COMMIT
```

And the C# code:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgartikulli.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertpurchase", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@supplier", cmbsupplier.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@billnr", txtbillnr.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", DateTime.Now));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@total", txttotali.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@note", txtnote.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@barcode", row.Cells[0].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stock", row.Cells[3].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", row.Cells[2].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sup_price", row.Cells[4].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@earn", row.Cells[1].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fitimi", row.Cells[5].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@category", row.Cells[6].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@unit", row.Cells[9].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vat", row.Cells[7].Value));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Insertion of transaction failed" + ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgartikulli.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertproducts", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@barcode", row.Cells[0].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stock", row.Cells[3].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", row.Cells[2].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sup_price", row.Cells[4].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@earn", row.Cells[1].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fitimi", row.Cells[5].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@category", row.Cells[6].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@unit", row.Cells[9].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vat", row.Cells[7].Value));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
    fshi();

    MessageBox.Show("Transaction is saved successfully");
}
```

The insert is done, but I want it to be made in a relationship of one to many. For example in table one only one row with general information of the bill, and in the second table the details of the bill(products information). With the above code I am getting in table one as much rows as in table two. For example if I have four rows with product information in table two, I am getting same repeated data in four rows in table with general data of the purchase bill, instead of just one row. My question is what to do, in order to achieve a one to many insertion(one row for general info of purchase- table) and (many rows for purchased product info-table)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to insert 1 `tblsuppling_general` record and multiple `tblpurchase_details`. Personally I would use a single SP and use a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) to pass in the details so you can pass as many as you need in.

Comment: I second a TVP, it's pretty efficient. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065761/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-error-when-passing-a-table-valued-parameter-t/66067309#66067309) for how to pass it to your procedure. By the way, you should dispose your connection and command objects with `using`, specify parameter types and lengths/scale explicitly, and should not block the thread with a messagebox while the connection is open

Answer (score 0):

You can break your procedure in two, one for the `tblsuppling_general` and another for the `tblpurchase_details`.

Or you can change your current procedure to:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tblsuppling_general WHERE 
)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblsuppling_general (Supplier, Bill_nr, Date, Total, Note)
        VALUES (@supplier, @billnr, @date, @total, @note)
    END

etc...
```

But be aware that this kind of insert-if-not-exists is problematic under heavy load because the execution of `IF NOT EXISTS` and `INSERT INTO` are not atomic.

Personally, I recommend using two procedures.