# Split values from many columns accordingly over multiple rows

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, excel, t-sql

Firstly i obatin data from Excel and convert them into `DataTable` in C# project.
Secondly i parse this `DataTable` into JSON string and send it to database as a stored procedure parameter.

I want to perform the merge operation on some table with values from this JSON string parameter.
Values from this parameter can be represented as such table:

```
DECLARE @JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @JsonData = N'[
     {"id": 1, "lval": "-10;15", "hval": "-20;45", "unit": "kg;m"}
     ]';


DECLARE @ExampleTable TABLE (EQ BIGINT, L_VALUE NVARCHAR(100), H_VALUE NVARCHAR(100), UNIT NVARCHAR (30))
INSERT INTO @ExampleTable
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JsonData) WITH (
[EQ] BIGINT 'strict $.id',
[L_VALUE] NVARCHAR(100) '$.lval',
[H_VALUE] NVARCHAR(100) '$.hval',
[UNIT] NVARCHAR(20) '$.unit')

SELECT * FROM @ExampleTable
```

| EQ (ID) | L_VALUE (nvarchar(100)) | H_VALUE (nvarchar(100)) | UNIT(nvarchar(30)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -10;15 | -20;45 | kg;m |

The first value (from either L_VALUE or H_VALUE) before the semicolon stands for the first unit from the UNIT column, second stands for second unit etc...
There can be more pairs of values and units or there can be simply one value one unit so in example:

| EQ (ID) | L_VALUE (nvarchar(100)) | H_VALUE (nvarchar(100)) | UNIT(nvarchar(30)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3;21;-19 | 2;11;-5 | kg;cm;ml |

or

| EQ (ID) | L_VALUE (nvarchar(100)) | H_VALUE (nvarchar(100)) | UNIT(nvarchar(30)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | -2 | cm |

I would like to obtain the result in the table form as follows:

| EQ (ID FK) | L_VALUE (float) | H_VALUE (float)) | UNIT (nvarchar(30)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -10 | -20 | kg |
| 1 | 15 | 45 | m |

Comment: Will there only every be 2 delimited values?

Comment: First question: why don't you use `SqlBulkCopy` or a table parameter instead of messing around with JSON. You already have a `DataTable` it's really easy

Comment: @Larnu there can be more as written in question "(there can be more pairs of values and units)" so the number of values varies

Comment: @Charlieface I perform many other operations (with differnet tables aswell) inside this stored procedure concernig this JSON string, it is just a short part of it that I am struggling with.

Comment: Again: why are you using JSON if you already have a `DataTable`? You can pass in an actual table as mentioned, and still do "many other operations" by joining the temp table or TVP. Why struggle with JSON if you don't have to? [See here for example how to send a `DataTable` as a TVP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067309/14868997). And if you really need it as JSON, then in C# make sure it's created correctly in the first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to transform the values in the `L_VALUE`, `H_VALUE` and `UNIT` columns as JSON (`-10;25` into `["-10", "-25"]`) and parse the values with additional `OPENJSON()` call. The result from the second `OPENJSON()` is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of an array, the `key` column contains the index of each item in the JSON array, so you need an appropriate `JOIN`s:

Table and JSON:

```
DECLARE @JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @JsonData = N'[
     {"id": 1, "lval": "-10;15", "hval": "-20;45", "unit": "kg;m"},
     {"id": 2, "lval": "-10;15;13", "hval": "-20;45;55", "unit": "kg;m;cm"},
     {"id": 3, "lval": "-10", "hval": "-20", "unit": "kg"}
]';
DECLARE @ExampleTable TABLE (
   EQ BIGINT, 
   L_VALUE NVARCHAR(100), 
   H_VALUE NVARCHAR(100), 
   UNIT NVARCHAR (30)
)
```

Statement:

```
INSERT INTO @ExampleTable
SELECT j.[EQ], a.[L_VALUE], a.[H_VALUE], a.[UNIT]
FROM OPENJSON(@JsonData) WITH (
   [EQ] BIGINT 'strict $.id',
   [L_VALUE] NVARCHAR(100) '$.lval',
   [H_VALUE] NVARCHAR(100) '$.hval',
   [UNIT] NVARCHAR(20) '$.unit'
) j
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT l.[value], h.[value], u.[value]
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(j.L_VALUE, ';', '","'), '"]')) l
   JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(j.H_VALUE, ';', '","'), '"]')) h ON l.[key] = h.[key]
   JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(j.UNIT, ';', '","'), '"]')) u ON l.[key] = u.[key]
) a (L_VALUE, H_VALUE, UNIT)
```

Result:

```
EQ L_VALUE H_VALUE UNIT
----------------------
1  -10     -20     kg
1  15      45      m
2  -10     -20     kg
2  15      45      m
2  13      55      cm
3  -10    -20      kg
```

Comment: Thank you, i think that solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* that there can only be 2 delimited values, and that there are **always** 2 delimited values, then you could do this:

```sql
SELECT JD.EQ,
       V.L_VALUE,
       V.H_VALUE,
       V.UNIT
FROM OPENJSON(@JsonData)
     WITH (EQ bigint '$.id',
           lval varchar(100),
           hval varchar(100),
           unit nvarchar(20)) JD
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(LEFT(JD.lval,CHARINDEX(';',JD.lval)-1),LEFT(JD.hval,CHARINDEX(';',JD.hval)-1),LEFT(JD.unit,CHARINDEX(';',JD.unit)-1)),
                       (STUFF(JD.lval,1,CHARINDEX(';',JD.lval),''),STUFF(JD.hval,1,CHARINDEX(';',JD.hval),''),STUFF(JD.unit,1,CHARINDEX(';',JD.unit),'')))V(L_VALUE,H_VALUE,UNIT)
```

I don't use `STRING_SPLIT` as it does not return the ordinal position, which could result in incorrect values being matched.