# Parameter '@stIdCity' was supplied multiple times asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to send values to a stored procedure via a listbox containing country names I get them from the database. If I choose one option code works 100% 100%. But if I put 2 or 3 options, I get the following error:

> Parameter '@stIdCity' was supplied multiple times.
>
> Line 322: da.Fill(ds);

Full code:

```
protected void lstBoxTestCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Tprocedure", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            foreach (ListItem item in lstBoxTestCity.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stIdCity", item.Value);
                }
            }
                
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            gvProducts.DataSource = ds;
            gvProducts.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Tprocedure
    (@stIdCity NVARCHAR(20) = NULL, )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM employees
    INNER JOIN TCity ON employees.IdstICity = TCity.IdstICity 
    WHERE (employees.IdstICity IN (SELECT ITEM 
                                   FROM dbo.SplitString(@stIdCity, ',')) 
       OR ISNULL(@stIdCity, '') = '')
END
```

Image of list:

[image]

Please help to solve the problem.

Sorry if the question was repeated, but I could not find a solution to it.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Hello, thanks for your reply, how can I do that if I can share some code. Sorry but I'm not much of an expert to do that

Comment: I would strongly suggest you convert this procedure to use a Table Valued Parameter, or at the very least JSON or XML

Comment: Hello / Thanks for your suggestion / Can you share some links example of that @Charlieface

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067309/14868997, although there are many tutorials online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ONLY have the ONE parmater, and it is a comma delimited string of values.

So, you have to "build up" a comma delimited string. Say like this:

```
        string myparms = "";
        foreach (ListItem item in lstBoxTestCity.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                if (myparms != "")
                    myparms += ",";

                myparms += item.Value;

            }
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stIdCity",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = myparms;
```

So, you only passing one value - but you have to build up the "string" of values to pass.

Answer (score 3):

You have this:

```
foreach (ListItem item in lstBoxTestCity.Items)
{
   if (item.Selected)
   {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stIdCity", item.Value);
   }
}
```

so for each selected city, you add a *new* parameter. That is why you get that error message.

Apparently you want one parameter, with a comma-separated value. So build that:

```
var value = string.Join(",",lstBoxTestCity.Items.Where(it => it.IsSelected).Select(it => it.Value));

cmd.Parameters.Add("@stIdCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = value;
```

First I use LINQ to filter for selected items, then I get their value. `string.Join` combines the resulting values with commas.

But do note that your stored procedure accepts just a `nvarchar(20)`, so you may run out of space when multiple cities have been selected.

Comment: Hello brother, thanks for your reply/ I deleted the foreach line and the if (item.Selected) line and put the code you shared with me. There is a problem with the where conditional sentence as follows:
Error CS1061 'ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'ListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 1_main.aspx ,

How can this be resolved?

Comment: You are "missing a using directive": you will need a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file.

Comment: Yes, I added it, but the problem is still . Only in the sentence WHERE

Comment: That is strange, ListItemCollection implements `IEnumerable`, which should be enough for Linq. And both extension methods used (Where and Select) come from Linq. Are you sure you added it correctly (no errors there)? In Visual Studio you can use `Ctrl+.` (Control and dot) to let it fix some issues at the position of the cursor - does that help?

Comment: You mentioned aspx. Would this help: `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>` instead of the `using`?

Comment: That using directive seems to be correct. I don't know what is wrong with your new code

Comment: No problem bro, thanks for trying to help me and your time